# How to set the timeout of a functional tests with the Intern?

Tags: intern

I'm using Intern to write functional tests against a web app, and I would like to define a timeout > 30s (30s is the default timeout for Intern tests) for each of my functional tests.

I cannot find anything related in the documentation. Does anybody knows how to do this ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information is available in the [Asynchronous Testing](https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Writing-Tests-with-Intern#asynchronous-testing) documentation. Set `this.timeout` from within the test to a value in milliseconds.