# How can I set the timeout for all intern tests?

Tags: intern

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861678/how-to-set-the-timeout-of-a-functional-tests-with-the-intern), and setting `this.timeout` works for me when done for each test individually. Is there a way to set it for all tests? I tried putting it in the suite (in the `return all([...` section) as well as in the config file, but neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently a built-in way to globally set the asynchronous test timeout or to change the default from 30000 ms. As pointed out in the question, the timeout can be set on a per-test basis by setting `this.timeout`. You can also call `this.async` with a timeout.

Note that the timeout is only meaningful for async tests, not necessarily all tests (although to be honest I don't think I've ever seen a sync test that lasted 30 seconds).